# Inserting an image as a facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot2` to produce faceted plots in a function (i.e., the number of facets varies). For each plot that I've produced, I'd like to insert one image (e.g. imported `jpg`) in a free facet at the end (i.e., `ggplot2` has to calculate the `facet_wrap` design in a way that foresees the existence of an additional facet, but this facet would be filled with a non-`ggplot2` image afterwards). Here is an MWE of a faceted plot, in this case I'd like to insert an image as the 4th facet:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~cyl, ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(png)

img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl, ncol = 2)

g <- ggplotGrob(p)
library(gtable)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, rasterGrob(img), nrow(g)-4, ncol(g)-2)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found this to be not very flexible because you have to specify the number of columns, and you assume that the number of facets is not even. I'm looking for a solution where `facet_wrap` would still calculate the number and location of facets as usually, but it would that there is one more facet than variable levels, and this last empty facet is then to be filled with the image.

Answer (score 0):

baptiste's solution was throwing an error for me; I had to direct some of the grid functions to the {grid} package, the code below should overcome this. Though I am not seeing the R logo appear.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(png)

img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl, ncol = 2)
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
library(gtable)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, grid::rasterGrob(img), nrow(g)-4, ncol(g)-2)
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(g)
```